# beautifulsoup find() attribute names with hyphens

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I made a parser, you need it to compare ID dates every 30 minutes for parsing new content. But I can't use the "-" sign, what should I do?

The problem is `date-time=True`

```
import telebot
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "****"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("div", class_="largeTitle", date-time=True)
post_id = post["date=time"]
```

Comment: By "made a parser" do you mean "use beautiful soup"?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right

Comment: And what do you intend `date-time=True` to mean?

Comment: Throws an error because of the dash

Comment: @mkrieger1 OP wants to search the element where the attribute `date-time` exists.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `attributes` argument to specify the attributes in a dictionary, rather than named arguments, when the attribute name isn't a valid Python name.

```
post = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "largeTitle", "date-time": True})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selector as well `"div.largeTitle[date-time]"`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """\
<div class="largeTitle" date-time="xxx">This I want</div>
<div class="largeTitle">This I don't</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

post = soup.select_one("div.largeTitle[date-time]")
print(post)
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="largeTitle" date-time="xxx">This I want</div>
```